# How can I fix mouse pointer inside a div element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, locking, mouse

I am developing online exam system.
So I have made examination environment with javascript and html.
All questions are laid in  element.
But I need make participants to not move mouse out of that div element.
I am looking for solution.
Please help me.
Thank you for read this.

Comment: That is not going to be done in the browser. Most places require you to download a custom browser that locks down the system.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a perfect solution you can try:

Setting the default `cursor` to `none` and give each div that you want locked a class of `locked`. The locked class will then have a cursor set to pointer (or whatever you want).

Then having in Javascript any click that wasn't done on a locked div, simply won't do anything with `e.preventDefault`

```js
_body = document.querySelector("body");

_body.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    if(e.target.className.indexOf("locked") == -1){
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

```css
*{cursor:none;}
.locked{width:300px;height:300px;background:red;cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<div class="locked">adsdad</div>

<a href="https://google.com">aaa</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your collaboration. Dubinkin.